# I'm trying to make a login page but its not working

Tags: javascript

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="login"> <input type="text" placeholder="user name" name="userid"><br> <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="pswrd"><br><br> <input type="button" onclick "check(this.form)" value="Login" /> </form>
    <script>
    function check(form) {
        if (form.userid.value == "name" && form.pswrd.value == "password") {
            window.open('https://www.youtube.com')
        } else {
            alert("wrong")
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

its not working... every time I try it it does not read the code.

Comment: Please see [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question so we may be able to help you.

Comment: If you mean your check function isn't begin called you're missing `=` in `onclick "check(this.form)"`

Comment: Please include more information, what specifically is not working? are you getting error? if so what are they?

Answer (score 1):

You have missed `=` operator after `onclick`

```
<input type = "button" onclick "check(this.form)" value ="Login"/>
                              ^
```